# Update a SQL Server database from an Entity Framework Model

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework-6

I'm using VB.net, EF6 with SQL Server 2008R2 database.

This is the situation: I have created the application. Using wizard I have created the Entity model from an existing database.

A client started using this application using this database on his computer.

After some months, I made some modifications on the database and I have updated the model on my application.

Now I have a new .exe file that has the new model from the new database.

I put the new .exe file on the client computer.

Now on his computer, the .exe file has the new database model, but the SQL Server database has the old structure.

I want to know: is possible to update the database structure from the entity model on application?

I want to add a command on application that can make (if is possible) this update, so the database become up to date according to entity model?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

If you have applied code-first approach, then you should go for below solution , given on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx), so your generated script will be 'idempotent'.

```
Run the Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase -TargetMigration: AddPostAbstract command in Package Manager Console
```

after going through it and still facing issue then try below command

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:0
```

Comment: I have fist created the database on sql server management studio , and after from existing database through wizard I create the entity inside my application. It seems that I'm using Database first and not code first , or I'm wrong ? So if I'm using Database first , how can I use the solution ?

Comment: ok ,yes you are right, it seems you are using Database first approach. unfortunately there is no effective solution for migration for database first approach, try to generate a database script and give client to run in his database and it will work for client and so for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try and deploy the database as a data-tier application. It will make managing migrations and upgrades a lot easier. More info here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210546.aspx